# contenteditable not working properly with cdkDrag on google-chrome

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, contenteditable

I simply trying to make a div editable. It was working like a charm on chrome before adding Drag-n-drop to my component with cdkDrag directive. 
However, it works fine with FireFox and Edge and it does show the input cursor.

```html
 <app-note-item  
      *ngFor=" let note of notes"
      cdkDrag
      [note] = "note"
      class="note-item"
      [cdkDragFreeDragPosition] = "note.position"
  ></app-note-item>
```

App-note-item :

```html
<div contenteditable="true"   class="note-content">

      {{note.content}}
  </div>
```

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. But I think `contenteditable` is also not fully functioning on FireFox with `cdkDrag`, if you want to double click to select a word, or select a part of paragraph, it is not working.
Please update if you have any progress~

Comment: Hi Wayne, yes unfortunately its not stable with other browsers too, so as an alternative solution i just used the html textarea

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61128879/5214911) for a solution.